# Найти количество элементов массива, меньших заданного

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Надо было найти количество элементов массива, меньших заданного в отсортированном массиве без повторений. Причем сделать это надо максимально быстро. Я использовал бинпоиск, вот что у меня вышло.

Почему-то работает не всегда. В чем может быть проблема?

```
int binary_search(std::vector<int> A, int x, int left, int right)
{
   while (right - left > 1)
   {
      int mid = (left + right) / 2;
      if (A[mid] < x)
      {
         left = mid;
      }
      else
      {
         right = mid;
      }
   }
   if (x <= A[0])
   {
      return 0;
   }
   return left + 1;
}
```

Comment: Правильно написать бинарный поиск — сложная задача. Даже Дональд Кнут (знаете?) в своей книге говорит, что почти все (в том числе он сам) с первой попытки пишут неправильно. Вот вам [статья по теме](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146228/).

Comment: Точно. Я тоже не с первой попытки написал несколько обобщенных функций (типа [man 3 bsearch](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch)) [bsearcher, bsearch_lb, bsearch_ub](http://pastebin.com/kv45jnVg)  на Си. (отличие от стандартной bsearch см. в комментариях по ссылке)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В вашей реализации неверно отрабатывал вариант, когда вы в качестве `x` передаете переменную, значение которой больше любого элемента массива (правда на самом деле у вас `vector`, а не массив, но не суть), а также в конце вы сравниваете с `A[0]`, а не с `A[left]`, хотя по логике вещей с ним бы и нужно сравнивать (ведь вы в границах диапазона решаете задачу, по крайней мере судя по входным параметрам).

В вашем коде минимальными усилиями можно решить данную проблему если заменить вот этот кусок:

```
if (x <= A[0])
{
    return 0;
}
```

на следующий:

```
if (x <= A[left])
   return 0;
else if (x > A[right])
   return (right - left + 1);
```

Кстати, будет эффективнее, если вы эту проверку переместите в начало процедуры, а не в конец.

Ну и в начале неплохо бы проверять `left` и `right` на вхождение в границы диапазона (ну и что `left <= right`), а то в итоге `mid`, через значение которого по индексу вы затем обращаетесь, может выйти из них.

А еще экземпляр `vector`'а передавайте по ссылке с модификатором `const` (не вы же не меняете объект внутри функции), чтобы в лишний раз не вызывать конструктор копирования.

---

Либо можно несколько поменять логику работы:

```
int binary_search(const std::vector<int>& arr, int key, int left, int right)
{
   left = (left < 0) ? 0 : left;
   right = (right > arr.size() - 1) ? arr.size() - 1 : right;
   do
   {
      int middle = (left + right) / 2;

      if (key < arr[middle])
         right = middle - 1;
      else if (key > arr[middle])
         left = middle + 1;
      else
      {
         for (; (middle >= 0) && (key == arr[middle]); --middle){}
         return middle + 1;
      }

      if (left > right)
         return left;
   } while (true);
}
```

Comment: @VladD Угу, я там промежуточный вариант зря выложил)

Comment: Пока я писал тот комментарий, вы исправили код :)

Comment: А ещё код ТС не взлетит из-за проверки `A[0]` после цикла. Пример: `A = {0, 1, 2}, x = 2`.

Comment: @VladD Я тут потестировал, вроде в его коде правильно отрабатывает такая ситуация (выдает 2).

Comment: И правда :) Буду копать дальше, очень уж мне не нравится использование `A[0]`, а не `A[l]`. // Хотя, это проверка выхода за левую границу, может он и прав тут.

Comment: Хм, и правда, глупость я написал насчёт `A[0]`. Его по идее можно просто проверять до цикла, он от l/r/mid не зависит.

Comment: @VladD Да, кстати, можно заранее эти проверки прокинуть если подумать, и если уж не прошли, то идти по алгоритму :)

Comment: @VladD Я тут, все-таки, подумал: а ведь и правда передаются граничные индексы `left` и `right`, а сравнение идет с `A[0]` - косяк, что-то как-то сразу в глаза не бросилось :)

Comment: Точно! Я смотрел на это в упор, но не сообразил. Вечером голова не работает уже. :)

Comment: @VladD У меня, как видимо, тоже - думаю, что нам стоит пойти спать :)

Comment: Точно! Спокойной ночи!

Answer (score 8):

Проще всего воспользоваться стандартным алгоритмом [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), который возвращает итератор на первый элемент, который *не меньше* данного.

[Пример](http://ideone.com/EzwPrJ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5 };
    const int pivot = 4;
    auto pos = std::lower_bound(std::begin(v), std::end(v), pivot);
    std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(v), pos);
    return 0;
}
```

Асимптотика алгоритма логарифмическая, т. к. он внутри реализует бинарный поиск.

Comment: Я так понял, что ему принципиально написать реализацию самому (ну, задача из учебного заведения, наверное), а не воспользоваться готовым решением, хотя, по факту мне стоило бы у него уточнить.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive: Тогда пусть будет два решения: вручную и со стандартной функцией. Одно из них точно подойдёт, а другое пригодится будущим читателям.

Comment: Тоже верно, вариант наверняка :)