# Можно ли найти в отсортированном векторе элемент с минимальной разностью с x быстрее?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Надо было найти в отсортированном векторе элемент, который отличается от данного x меньше всего (разность минимальна).

Я сделал это вот так:

```
int dist(const std::vector<int>& A, int x) {
    int min = 10000000000;
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != A.size(); i++) {
        if (abs(A[i] - x) < min) {
            min = abs(A[i] - x);
            ans = i;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Можно ли сделать это быстрее по времени?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разумеется.

Вам нужен `std::lower_bound`, который вернёт итератор на первый элемент, больший или равный вашему `x`. Вам придётся ещё проверить предыдущий элемент.

Оба элемента могут не существовать: результат `std::lower_bound` может указывать за последним элементом контейнера (в этом случае первое сравнение пропускаете), а также указывать на начальный элемент контейнера (в этом случае второе сравнение пропускаете).

Индекс найденного элемента можно спросить у итератора:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { -5, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10 };
    const int x = 3;
    auto igreater = std::lower_bound(std::begin(v), std::end(v), x);
    auto iless = (igreater == std::begin(v)) ? std::end(v) : (igreater - 1);
    auto ibest =
        (igreater == std::end(v)) ? iless :
        (iless == std::end(v)) ? igreater :
        (x - *iless) < (*igreater - x) ? iless : igreater;
    if (ibest == std::end(v))
    {
        std::cout << "error: empty array?";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "best diff = " << std::abs(x - *ibest)
                  << " at index " << std::distance(std::begin(v), ibest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/pVRVec).

Comment: А как тогда найти номер этого элемента в векторе? Просто эта функция у меня используется в остальном коде, а его менять тяжелее.

Comment: Раз он не хочет работать с итераторами, то может ему тоже стоит воспользоваться бинарным поиском из [нашего прошлого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495182/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/495188#495188)? :D Ведь задача практически идентичная.

Comment: Кстати, да. Задача в любом случае на двоичный поиск. так что имеет смысл адаптировать алгоритм из другого вопроса.

Comment: @Parket, вычесть begin.

Answer (score 3):

Продолжая тенденцию [прошлого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495182/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/), могу предложить аналогичное @VladD-овскому решение, но без использования `stl`-ых функций (вдруг вам принципиально), посредством все того же бинарного поиска:

```
int binary_search(const std::vector<int>& arr, int key)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = arr.size() - 1;
    do
    {
        if (left >= right)
            return arr[right];
        else
        {
            int middle = (left + right) / 2;

            if (key < arr[middle])
                right = middle - 1;
            else if (key > arr[middle])
                left = middle + 1;
            else
                return arr[middle];
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

---

Название вашей функции `dis` (как видимо от `distance`) может ввести в заблуждение: ведь вы возвращаете значение максимально близкого элемента массива, хотя название намекает на то, что должно бы возвращаться расстояние до этого элемента (например, между 10 и 7 расстояние 3).

Answer (score 2):

Я обновил свой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495276/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-4-%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0/495528#495528) по прошлому вопросу, поскольку для целочисленных массивов ответ можно протабулировать.

Для этого надо создать массив гистограмм, в котором для каждого знвчения в допустимом диапазоне указан индекс последнего элемента отсортированного исходного массива, который не превосходит это значение.

Процедура формирования массива гистограмм такая:
1. Создаётся и заполняется нулями массив гистограмм требуемой размерности.
2. В цикле по исходному массиву прибавляются единицы в позициях массива гистограмм с индексом, равным текущему значению исходного массива.
3. Заводится переменная-сумматор с начальным значением -1.
4. В цикле по массиву гистограмм к сумматору добавляется значение текущего элемента массива, а полученное значение записывается в текущуую позицию массива.